# Blazor Serialize object without blocking UI thread

Tags: c#, json, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a large [datasource](https://geoconfirmed.org/api/placemark/Ukraine) that is a JSON array that needs to be converted into a List.

To speed up serialization I implemented [Utf8JsonAsyncStreamReader](https://github.com/gragra33/Utf8JsonAsyncStreamReader) and use that to serialize each object individually and add it to a List variable. This seems to be faster than the regular HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync method but sadly it still blocks the UI thread for about 20 seconds. I also tried working with [WebWorkers](https://github.com/LostBeard/SpawnDev.BlazorJS#spawndevblazorjswebworkers) but as soon as the webworker finished the UI thread also gets blocked for such a long time, I assume because it transfers the object.

Is there a way to do this "async" in a way that serialization doesn't block the UI thread? Or at least not noticably long?

Below is an example of the code I use to serialize my object

```
        var reader = new Utf8JsonAsyncStreamReader(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
        var list = new List<SimplifiedPlacemark>();
        var simplifiedMark = new SimplifiedPlacemark();
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            JsonTokenType tokenType = reader.TokenType;

            switch (tokenType)
            {
                case JsonTokenType.StartObject:
                    simplifiedMark = new SimplifiedPlacemark();
                    break;
                case JsonTokenType.PropertyName:
                    switch (reader.Value.ToString())
                    {
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Id).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.Id = reader.GetGuid();
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Date).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.Date = reader.GetDateTime();
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Name).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.Name = reader.GetString();
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Description).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.Description = reader.GetString();
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Coordinates).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.Coordinates = await reader.DeserializeAsync<double[]>(jsonSerializerOptions);
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Icon).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.Icon = reader.GetString();
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.OriginalSource).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.OriginalSource = reader.GetString();
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Geolocation).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.Geolocation = reader.GetString();
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Units).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.Units = reader.GetString();
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Units).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.Units = reader.GetString();
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Origin).ToLowerInvariant():
                            if (reader.TryGetByte( out byte? org)) {
                                simplifiedMark.Origin = (Origin)org;
                                    };
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.AllGeolocations).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.AllGeolocations = reader.GetBoolean() ?? false;
                            break;
                        case var value when value == nameof(SimplifiedPlacemark.Gear).ToLowerInvariant():
                            simplifiedMark.Gear = reader.GetString();
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case JsonTokenType.EndObject:
                    list.Add(simplifiedMark);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Serialization is slow and you need all the data before you can deserialize so Async won't help.  the only way of speeding up is to speed up the transfer rate.  Try WebSocket : https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/5aaff6b010b0785075b0a08cc1e40e01

Comment: You can add an `await Task.Delay(1)` after `case JsonTokenType.EndObject:`. The total time will increase but it might look better.